# Jquery UI Drag Drop How to Add an Information Message?

Tags: javascript, jquery, drag-and-drop

I'm doing a project with the Jquery UI Drag Drop library. But when I try to add an information message, the message can be resumed. When I try to do the insertion process, I encounter difficulties.

I want to add the message differently for each of the *2 boxes*.

How do I add a drag and drop message?

**Desired Output**: [https://i.stack.imgur.com/eBqi4.gif](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ofT1t.gif)

**CODES**: https://jsfiddle.net/bw5ky9r7/

```js
$(document).ready(function(){

 
 $("#deactive-cards").droppable({
   accept: "#active-cards > div",
 });
 $("#active-cards").droppable({
   accept: "#deactive-cards > div",
 });

 $("#deactive-cards, #active-cards").sortable({
   placeholder: "",
   connectWith: ".flex-container",
   containment: "#maximum-drag",
   revert: true,
   scroll: false,
   receive: function(event, ui) {
     $("#active-cards-count").text($("#active-cards").find("div").length);
   }
 });
  
  });
```

```css
 .flex-container {
   text-align: center;
   padding: 0;
   -webkit-user-select: none;
   -moz-user-select: none;
   -ms-user-select: none;
   user-select: none;
   margin: 5px 10px;
   min-height: 115px;
   overflow: hidden;
   flex-wrap: wrap;
   display: flex;
   align-items: center;
   justify-content: center;
   box-shadow: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.23) 0px 0px 5px 0px inset;
   background: rgb(249, 249, 249);
   padding: 15px 5px;
   border: 2px solid transparent;
 }

 .flex-container>div {
   cursor: all-scroll;
   margin: 3px 2px;
   text-align: center;
   flex-direction: row;
   height: 77px;
   display: inline-flex;
   align-items: center;
   justify-content: center;
   border-radius: 2px;
   border-bottom-width: 3px;
   padding: 10px;
   max-width: 92px;
   box-sizing: border-box;
   background: #ffffff;
   box-shadow: 0px 2px 2px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
   position: relative;
 }

 .flex-container>div>img {
   user-drag: none;
   user-select: none;
   -moz-user-select: none;
   -webkit-user-drag: none;
   -webkit-user-select: none;
   -ms-user-select: none;
 }

 .title-box {
   padding: 10px;
   position: relative;
 }

 .title-box h5 {
   text-transform: uppercase;
   color: #11acbe;
   font-size: 17px;
   font-weight: 500;
   display: inline-block;
   margin-right: 10px;
   line-height: 1.1;
   position: relative;
   margin-bottom: 13px;
   padding-left: 5px;
 }

 .title-box h5:before {
   top: -5px;
   margin-bottom: 0;
   content: '';
   background-color: #11acbe;
   width: 3px;
   height: 30px;
   position: absolute;
   left: -10px;
 }

 .ui-droppable-active {
   box-shadow: none !important;
   background-image: radial-gradient(circle, rgba(237, 253, 255, 0.07), rgba(0, 205, 231, 0.1), rgba(0, 188, 212, 0.1), rgba(0, 188, 212, 0.15)) !important;
   border: 2px dashed #00bcd4 !important;
 }

 .ui-sortable-helper:before {
   content: " ";
   border: 2px solid #00bcd4;
   background-image: radial-gradient(circle, rgba(237, 253, 255, 0.07), rgba(0, 205, 231, 0.1), rgba(0, 188, 212, 0.1), rgba(0, 188, 212, 0.15));
   position: absolute;
   top: 0;
   right: 0;
   width: 100%;
   height: 100%;
 }
```

```html
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.8.21/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
  

<div class="col-lg-12" id="maximum-drag">
  <div class="title-box">
    <h5>ACTIVE DISPLAY CARDS (<span id="active-cards-count">0</span>)</h5>
    <div style="font-size: 14px;color: #6e6e6e;">It is a list of your display cards that are active on the server.</div>
  </div>
  <div class="flex-container" id="active-cards">

  </div>
  <div class="title-box">
    <h5>YOUR DISPLAY CARDS</h5>
    <div style="font-size: 14px;color: #6e6e6e;">List of display cards you can use.</div>
  </div>
  <div class="flex-container" id="deactive-cards">
    <div id="item-1"><img src="https://svgur.com/i/D1R.svg" style="width: 90%"></div>

  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Didn't you post [**This Question**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56094709/jquery-drag-drop-item-count-and-ajax-post-update?noredirect=1#comment98825649_56094709) or are you both working on the same assignment?

Comment: Now I saw the question. However, the answer is not included in this question.

Comment: You could do this with `css` for example `#active-cards:empty::before` [**JsFiddle Demo**](https://jsfiddle.net/New_To_JS/60wgeL7f/1/)

Comment: It worked for me. Thank you..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
#active-cards:empty:before{
             content: "Drag and drop the display cards you want to use here.";
             padding: 15px;
              text-shadow: 0px 1px 0px #ffffff;
            }
            #deactive-cards:empty:before{
               content: "All your display cards are being used.";
               padding: 15px;
                 text-shadow: 0px 1px 0px #ffffff;
            }
```